# C# ASP.NET MVC page is connecting to SQL Server session storage with domain user instead of database user

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, session-state

I have an ASP.NET MVC page that requires a session storage due to balancing, after researching the different solutions, it was chosen to use SQL Server session storage.

In the `web.config` file of my page, I added this:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="SQLServer" 
    stateConnectionString="Server=<myip>:42424;user id=user; password=MySApassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Application Name=MyApp" 
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
    cookieless="false" 
    timeout="15"/>
```

But when I run my application from Visual Studio, I get this message:

> SQL Server Login failed for user DOMAIN\MyPCUser

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

It seems the IIS is not logging with the specified user to the SQL Server, instead it's trying to use my local pc user (which is a domain user).

On the side of my SQL Server, when using SQL Server Management Studio, I can log in using those credentials and perform actions such as select on the tables that where created for session storage.

This is the command used to create the storage:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regsql -d SessionStorage -S
 <serverIP> -U <user> -P <mypassword> -ssadd -sstype c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to to see the state of the [error here on MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555332/login-failed-for-user-error-message-when-you-log-on-to-sql-server)

- First, look at what your Web App is Running under
  ApplicationPoolIdentity Web Application connecting to databases
  through ADO.Net using Windows Authentication in the connection string
  The connection string used with Windows authentication include either `Trusted_Connection=Yesattribute` or the equivalent attribute `Integrated Security=SSPI` in `Web.config`
- If your database connection is in Windows Authentication mode. Then resolve it by simply changing the Application Pools Identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to your  domain login credentials DomainName\MyloginId

Step:

1. Click on Application Pools
2. Select Name of your application

Go to Advanced Setting

*Expand Process Model and click Identity. Click three dot on right end.
Click Set... button and Provide your domain log in credentials
For me it was resolved.*

Note: In Production or IT environment, if have service account under same domain for app pool identity. Then use service account instead of your login.